# Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout

I am trying to add `Order Comments` field in checkout.

I am following [this Tutorial](http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-add-order-comment-on-customer-checkout-in-magento/)

I am using Magento 1.8

I am getting below error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_store\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php on line 1390`

can anyone have any idea about the error?

Comment: Seems like your attribute could not be found. Verify that it exists by browsing through the admin panel `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes`

Comment: visit this link http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-add-order-comment-on-customer-checkout-in-magento/ I have created attribute directly in database

Comment: Regardless of how you created the attribute, you should be able to see it by Browsing `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes`. If you cannot see it in there, it is probably not added correctly.

Comment: I just read that tutorial briefly, it's for adding an attribute to the order model and your error is within the product model. Have you tried using an order example for a product attribute, or made some similar mistake?

Comment: well i have pasted exact code as it is in tutorial, does tutorial have any mistake?

Comment: all i want is to add field for Order Comments in checkout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22696/discussion-between-androidjunky-and-luke-rodgers).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28683390/revisions

Until Mage team didn't include it into the core, you can extend core class and rewrite this one method.

Comment: This isn't the right way, just dirty workaround.

Comment: Two years since, and they didn't include this useful change into the core? Anyway, looks like it's time to use community supported M1.